# "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" when using @Primary on one of the two SQLSessionFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, mybatis

I have two datasources in place both are working fine separately. But, when I use `@Primary` on one of the two SqlSessionFactory the other starts throwing exception mentioned below :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pServiceImpl': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:   Error querying
>   database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table
>   or view does not exist
>
> The error may exist in com/abc/def/mapper/pMapper.java (best guess)
>
> The error may involve defaultParameterMap
>
> The error occurred while setting parameters
>
> SQL: select C.CONTACT_ID, C.REF_ID, S.P_ID, S.COURIER_P_NUM, S.SENDER_ADDR_ID, S.CREATION_TS,
>   CA.CONTACT_ADDR_ID from P_EVENT_TRACKING SE, P S,
>   CONTACT_ADDR CA, CONTACT C where SE.EVENT_CD = 'PICKUP' and
>   SE.P_ID = s.p_id and S.SENDER_ADDR_ID =
>   CA.CONTACT_ADDR_ID and CA.CONTACT_ID = c.contact_id and C.GROUP_CD =
>   'OT' and SE.EVENT_OCCURRED_IND = 'N' and S.CREATION_TS >= (select
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '30' day from dual)and
>   S.SCHEDULE_PICKUP_IND = 'Y'
>
> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at
>   com.abc.def.app.starter.Pickup.main(Pickup.java:11)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>
> Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> The error may exist in com/abc/def/mapper/PMapper.java (best guess)
>
> The error may involve defaultParameterMap
>
> The error occurred while setting parameters
>
> SQL: select C.CONTACT_ID, C.REF_ID, S.P_ID, S.COURIER_P_NUM, S.SENDER_ADDR_ID, S.CREATION_TS,
>   CA.CONTACT_ADDR_ID from P_EVENT_TRACKING SE, P S,
>   CONTACT_ADDR CA, CONTACT C where SE.EVENT_CD = 'PICKUP' and
>   SE.P_ID = s.p_id and S.SENDER_ADDR_ID =
>   CA.CONTACT_ADDR_ID and CA.CONTACT_ID = c.contact_id and C.GROUP_CD =
>   'OT' and SE.EVENT_OCCURRED_IND = 'N' and S.CREATION_TS >= (select
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '30' day from dual)and
>   S.SCHEDULE_PICKUP_IND = 'Y'
>
> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist
>
> at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.selectList(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)
>     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.findPByOutlet(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.abc.def.dao.PDAOImpl.getPByOutlet(PDAOImpl.java:23)
>     at
>   com.abc.def.service.PickupServiceImpl.startExecution(PickupServiceImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   com.abc.def.service.PickupServiceImpl.execute(PickupServiceImpl.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>     ... 13 more

Comment: You may consider 'P' as valid table name (let say POWER), I just renamed it as I can not publish the real name. Also, SQL query is correct as it is working fine when I remove annotate from first and place on the second SQLSessionFactory with @Primary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing of the placement of the `@Primary` annotation fixes this it means that in your spring configuration you are using autowiring by type of the `SqlSessionFactory` into `SqlSessionTemplate` that is used by `PDAOImpl` or autowiring by type of the `SqlSessionTemplate` in the `PDAOImpl`.

Make sure that you specify correct dependency explicitly.

You get this error because `PDAOImpl` uses incorrect `SqlSessionFactory` which makes calls to the database that does not have that table.

Comment: Thank you explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this. Removed auto-registration of mapper (i.e `@Mapper`) and manually registered Mapper in `SQLSessionTemplate` as shown below:

```
 @Bean
    public TestMapper testMapper() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionTemplate sessionTemplate = new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory());        
        sessionTemplate.getConfiguration().addMapper(TestMapper.class); // new code
        return sessionTemplate.getMapper(TestMapper.class);
    }
```